# Access Sign in Module

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to create a finance database that requires users to sign in and log out. I have that part working correctly. On the homepage of the database, I'm trying to get their last 25 (or X number) of transactions to display using a query. For some reason, I cannot get the code to pass as it shows a "Data type mismatch." Here is the various code - I'll explain each as I go:

Global Variables (My Global Module)
Option Compare Database

'global variables
    Global C As Long
    Global C2 As Long
    Global HoldString As String
    Global Flag As Boolean
    Global Reply As String
    Global mbReply As VbMsgBoxResult

```
Global User As String
Global GUser As Long

Global db As Database
```

The following are the Subs() to Log In (First Sub() is for Exit button, second sub() is for sign in button):

Option Compare Database

Private Sub B_Exit_Click()

```
mbReply = MsgBox(title:="Exit", _
    prompt:="Are you sure you wish to exit the system?", _
    Buttons:=vbYesNo)

If mbReply = vbNo Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    DoCmd.Quit acQuitSaveNone
End If
```

End Sub

Private Sub B_SignIn_Click()
'variables
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Dim Employees As DAO.Recordset
    Set Employees = db.OpenRecordset("Employees", dbOpenDynaset)

```
Dim isEmployeed As Boolean
Dim PassMatch As Boolean
Dim isTerm As Boolean
```

'check to see if the user is in the system
    isEmployeed = False
    PassMatch = False
    isTerm = False

```
Do While Not Employees.EOF
    If Employees![UserName] = T_Username.Value Then
        isEmployeed = True

        'make sure the employee is not terminated
        If Employees![Terminated] = "Yes" Then
            isTerm = True
        End If
        If isTerm = True Then
            MsgBox ("This user has been terminated.")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'make sure password is correct
        If Employees![Password] = T_Password.Value Then
            PassMatch = True
        End If
        If PassMatch = False Then
            MsgBox ("Incorrect Password.")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'mark signed in
        Employees.Edit
        Employees![SignedIn] = 1
        Employees.Update
        User = Employees![FirstName] & " " & Employees![LastName]
        GUser = Employees![ID] 'Sets GUswer to equal record ID.
    End If
    Employees.MoveNext
Loop

If isEmployeed = False Then
    MsgBox ("This username is not in the system.")
    Exit Sub
End If
```

'close this form and open the main menu
    Employees.Close
    DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="HomePage"
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name, acSaveNo

End Sub

The next is my SQL code for the query:

SELECT TOP 25 Spend.ID, Spend.Vendor, Spend.MaterialGroup, Spend.GLCode, Spend.CostCenter, Spend.Department, Spend.InvoiceNumber, Spend.InvoiceDate, Spend.Amount, Spend.Tax, Spend.Total, Spend.DateEntered, Spend.DocNumber, Spend.Description, Spend.[Paid?], Spend.EnteredBy, Spend.EnteredBy

FROM Spend

WHERE (((Spend.[EnteredBy])="GUser"));

Spend.[EnteredBy] has a relationship with the Employees table. So EnteredBy is actually a number field because of this relationship.

If I hardcode the "WHERE" statement to be something like (((Spend.[EnteredBy])=2)); then the query will work fine.

Ultimately, what I want to happen is for the query to show the last 25 data entries that the logged on user completed.

Hope this makes sense. If there are questions, please let me know. I feel like I'm missing something small but I cannot figure it out.

Thanks,

Clark

Answer (score 0):

Your query should read:

```
SELECT TOP 25 Spend.ID, Spend.Vendor, Spend.MaterialGroup, Spend.GLCode, Spend.CostCenter,
Spend.Department, Spend.InvoiceNumber, Spend.InvoiceDate, Spend.Amount, Spend.Tax, Spend.Total, 
Spend.DateEntered, Spend.DocNumber, Spend.Description, Spend.[Paid?], Spend.EnteredBy, Spend.EnteredBy 
FROM Spend WHERE (((Spend.[EnteredBy])=" & GUser & "));
```

Note the Ampersands ( & ) I placed before and after your GUser variable. This tells Access to evalute that expression and return the VALUE of it.

I'd also caution you against use the name "User" as a variable name. It's a Reserved Word in Access:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx

Comment: I tried doing that and it still returns a data mismatch. Does it anything to do with the value of "GUser" not being passed to the Query? If I hardcode a number ie: Spend.[EnteredBy] = 3 then it works fine. For some reason, there seems to be an issue with "GUser" not being associated with a number.